# How do I see which files are in the usermode cache in IIS7.5?

Tags: iis, caching, isapi, http.sys

The kernelmode static content cache is part of HTTP.SYS and is rather straightforward to configure. When debugging, you can always inspect the contents of the kernelmode cache with the command:

```
netsh http show cachestate
```

But the usermode cache in IIS is much harder to debug. There seems to be no inspection possibilities at all. Is there a simple way to see what files are in the usermode cache inside the web applications worker process?

In our project we have an ISAPI module that does introspection into the requested file before returning them to the browser. Because of this we cannot use the standard static content cache in IIS. We are having problems with caching, where IIS stops adding new items to the cache after a short warmup period. Items get flushed, but no new files seems to get cached. According to perfmon the number of items in the cache falls down to a handful. It would be very valuable for us to be able to see exactly what files are in the cache at any given time.